# Having a challenge playing audio from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello there im kindly asking for assistance. Im having a challenge playing an audio whose path is located in a mysql database table. The mp3 file itself is saved inside an uploads folder that is on my local machine. So below i am displaying the path using the path variable and adding it to the src of my audio element.

here is a snippet of my code

```
<?php
            include_once("config.php");
            $sql = "SELECT title, text, path FROM content WHERE date=CURDATE()";
            $stmnt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
            $stmnt->execute();
            $result=$stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $title=$result->title;
            $text=$result->text;       
            $path = $result->path;
            echo $path;
            //display the path where the user will click and the player will play that audio file...
            //echo $path;   
            echo "<h4 style = 'color:white;'>$title</h4>";
            echo "<h4 style = 'color:white;'>$text</h4>";
            echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary  animate__animated animate__slideInUp' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'><i class = 'fa fa-music'></i>";
            echo "Music
            </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success  animate__animated animate__fadeInRight' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal2'><i class = 'fa fa-book'></i>";
            echo "Text
            </button>
             <br>
             <hr>";
             echo "<audio>
              <source src='$path' type='audio/mp3'>
            </audio>";
            ?>
          </div>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: the player or the audio bar is not playing anything. when i press play nothing happens

Comment: did you check your src ? is it correct ?